# How to close a question because the wrong approach is being used?

Tags: support, close-reasons, vote-to-close

Example:

[Animate the squares](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23583263/animate-the-squares/23583854)

The question has code, is pretty clear, but the technique used is wrong. Keyframe animations won't work here. A user has already tried to fix up the code that is supplied to make it work, but of course it never will.

I answered it with a brief "That won't ever work" answer. The questioner has said they don't know JS, so there is little point going into further detail.

I'd like to close it to stop further junk answers - what should it be closed as?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a *perfect* opportunity to provide a quality answer; one that both clears up any confusion from either the OP or others, and allow anyone reading this question to better understand or identify the actual problem that they're having.

A question like that is more suitable to be answered as opposed to put on-hold; if it's put on hold, then the misconception about the actual problem remains, and no one gains any knowledge, since the professionals can't provide a truly canonical answer to the actual question.

I would encourage you not to look at questions like this as candidates for closing/putting on hold.  If the answers themselves are misleading, then downvote them; if you feel that there is a better solution to the problem, by all means, provide it.

Answer (score 7):

The question is not off-topic, so why close it?

If the approach is wrong, then an answer explaining why would help the OP, and future visitors that similarly got the wrong idea.